# Removing space in-between text and select options

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML, and would like to remove the space between the text which is in a h5 tag, and the select options

HTML

```
<h5>Text</h5>
<select style="width:180px">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Select option</option>
</select>
```

The above code has a fair sized gap in between the two elements. I'm not sure what css to use in order to remove the gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use CSS in order to modify style for `h5` tag, for example:

```
h5 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The same goes for `option` tag if you wish to modify that as well.

From here you can try if you like that result or would you like to modify h5 tag even further (remember, that you can even have negative margin values).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: If you want to add space you need to wrap the select in a  and then use the margin-top css property

If you want to remove the gap, use the margin-bottom or padding-bottom css property for the h5.

Edit 2: You might want to use classes instead of directly changing the styles of the base html tags, to prevent unwanted effect in other places of your page.

Answer (score 0):

To remove any gaps you should set the `margin` and `padding` of both elements to `0`

```
h5, select {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
```